# Opening MS Word from a php page

Tags: php, ms-word

I have a customer who has a large php based web app. He wants to know if it is possible to use a php page to assemble a report (data from mysql database) and then at the click of a button open word 2010 on the client machine and load the report straight in.

I've done a bit of research that suggests it is possible but haven't found any specifics. Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: You could use something like [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) to generate the report, then by sending the correct headers, have the report "download" to the client machine (which would give the user the option to save or open).

Comment: Write a word document on the fly using the libraries mentioned here by others, then force the download

Comment: OK Thanx, How would I force the download?

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://phpword.codeplex.com/

It is a php library for parsing and creating MsWord documents.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the security measures in the browser, it's impossible to execute local programs by default. But you could make this feature work by creating a plugin for the browser (which would be able to open external programs but would require installation in the client machine).